# Is it possible to make odd-numbered columns have implicitly a prefix {}?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, mathtools

Prefix `{}` is implicitly inserted for even-numbered columns of `alignedat` (and `alignat`). As a result, `+` (or `-`, etc) becomes a binary operator.

The section "Left aligned" below

```
\begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
  {}+abc   &&{}+abcd &&{}+abcde\\
  {}+abcde &&{}+abcdef
\end{alignedat}
```

shows how the implicit prefix `{}` is used to align the operators.

The section "Right aligned" below

```
\begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
  &+abc   &&+abcd   &&+abcde\\
  &+abcde &&+abcdef
\end{alignedat}
```

shows the same equations but the variables (instead of the operators) are aligned.

My question: Is it possible to let `alignedat` (as well as `alignat`) provide implicit prefix `{}` for the odd-numbered columns to free me from inserting `{}` by hand which is error prone?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\section*{Right aligned}
$
\text{LHS} = \!
\begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
&+abc &&+abcd &&+abcde\\
&+abcde &&+abcdef
\end{alignedat}\\
$

\section*{Left aligned}
$
\text{LHS} = \!
\begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
{}+abc   &&{}+abcd &&{}+abcde\\
{}+abcde &&{}+abcdef
\end{alignedat}\\
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If all your alignments are `&&` it indicates that perhaps you're not using the optimum environment structure, `alignat` is optimised for the case where the cells are not mostly empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but I'm asking why one would like to display things this way.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,regexpatch}
\newcommand\hiddenplus{\hphantom{{}+{}}}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\regexpatchcmd{\start@aligned}
  {\cP.\cP.}             % change \displaystyle{##}
  {\cB\{\cE\}\cP\#\cP\#} % to \displaystyle{{}##}
  {}{}
\global\let\xstart@aligned\start@aligned
\endgroup
\newenvironment{lalignedat}
 {\let\start@aligned\xstart@aligned
  \let\@testopt\alignsafe@testopt
  \alignedat@a}
 {\endaligned}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
(x^2 +x +1)(3x^4 +13x^3 -18x^2 +11x -3)
&= \!
   \begin{alignedat}[t]{7}
     3x^6  &&{}+13x^5 &&{}-18x^4 &&{}+11x^3  &&{}-3x^2 \\
           &&{}+3x^5  &&{}+13x^4 &&{}-18x^3  &&{}+11x^2  &&{}-3x \\
           &&         &&{}+3x^4  &&{}+13x^3  &&{}-18x^2  &&{}+11x  &&{}-3
   \end{alignedat}\\
&= 3x^6 +16x^5 -2x^4 +6x^3 -10x^2 +8x -3
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
(x^2 +x +1)(3x^4 +13x^3 -18x^2 +11x -3)
&= \!
   \begin{lalignedat}[t]{7}
     3x^6  &&+13x^5 &&-18x^4 &&+11x^3  &&-3x^2 \\
           &&+3x^5  &&+13x^4 &&-18x^3  &&+11x^2  &&{}-3x \\
           &&       &&+3x^4  &&+13x^3  &&-18x^2  &&{}+11x  &&{}-3
   \end{lalignedat}\\
&= 3x^6 +16x^5 -2x^4 +6x^3 -10x^2 +8x -3
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

For the same in `align` and similar environments, you have to similarly patch `\align@preamble`; for instance you could define `lalign*` by

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\regexpatchcmd{\align@preamble}
  {\cP.\cP.}             % change \displaystyle{##}
  {\cB\{\cE\}\cP\#\cP\#} % to \displaystyle{{}##}
  {}{}
\global\let\xalign@preamble\align@preamble
\endgroup
\newenvironment{lalign*}
  {\let\align@preamble\xalign@preamble
   \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne}
  {\endalign}
\makeatother
```

Here's the comparison

[image]

Instead of using `\regexpatchcmd` you can copy the definitions of the relevant macros from `amsmath.sty` and add the pair of braces as shown.