# What is the command \span?

Tags: tables, tex-core

I have bumped into the `\span` primitive a couple of time. I got the impression it is defined in the TeX program, not even in `plain.tex`. Is that right? And what *does* that command do and what is it for?

Comment: Just from the name, for me it sounds like some sort of `\multicolumn`, like `\span 3` columns :P

Comment: I think it is used in `\multirow`. I remember reading it was used in `\multi`something, but I don't remember if something was row or column :). It is also used in `\sp@n`, which is LaTeX kernel.

Comment: Yep, `\multicolumn`->`\multispan`->`\@multispan`->`\sp@n`->`\span`. `\multirow` doesn't use it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The primitive `\span` has two very different meanings if it appear in the preamble of `\halign` or in the body.

If it's in the preamble, that is before the first `\cr` it means “expand” the following token; if it appears in the body it ends the current cell, but merges it with the following one. In this case it's usually in combination with `\omit`.

The simplest example is

```
\halign{\hfil#\tabskip1em&#\hfil\cr
  a&b\cr
  c\span d\cr
}
```

where the second row will have just one cell. The output will be

[image]

with no `\tabskip` spacing between “c” and “d”, because the second row is just one cell with `\hfil` before and after the contents, but TeX will take the `\tabskip` into account for determining the cell's width.

Usually, however, one also adds `\omit` in order to remove the *u* and *v* parts (*u* refers to what comes before `#`, *v* to what follows it).

When TeX is reading a preamble for `\halign` it doesn't expand tokens unless it finds `\tabskip` (when it expands tokens for finding the appropriate glue specification). Expansion of a token can be forced by preceding it with `\span`.

An example is in `amsmath.sty`

```
\def\align@#1#2{%
    \inalign@true \intertext@ \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\z@
    \ifingather@\else\displ@y@\fi
    \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@align
    \ifxxat@\else \let\tag\tag@in@align \fi
    \let\label\label@in@display
    #1% set st@r
    \ifst@rred\else \global\@eqnswtrue \fi
    \measure@{#2}%
    \global\row@\z@
    \tabskip\eqnshift@
    \halign\bgroup
        \span\align@preamble\crcr
        #2%
}
```

This is a helper macro used for `align` and friends; the preamble is defined once and for all in the macro `\align@preamble`

```
\def\align@preamble{%
   &\hfil
    \strut@
    \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \tabskip\z@skip
   &\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \hfil
    \tabskip\alignsep@
}
```

This greatly simplifies the definition of `\align@`, by placing a big chunk of code in a macro. It also allows for changing the behavior of `align` by modifying `\align@preamble` (see [Is it possible to make odd-numbered columns have implicitly a prefix {}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186446/is-it-possible-to-make-odd-numbered-columns-have-implicitly-a-prefix)).

The LaTeX kernel uses a different method for `tabular`, because it needs to build the preamble according to its rules, that is, a combination of `lcrp` characters and so on.

The second usage for `\span` is for merging columns in an `\halign`. In Plain TeX we find `\multispan`

```
\def\multispan#1{\omit \mscount#1\relax
  \loop\ifnum\mscount>\@ne \sp@n\repeat}
\def\sp@n{\span\omit\advance\mscount\m@ne}
```

that does `\omit` and adds as many `\span\omit` pairs as stated in the argument (minus one); so `\multispan{1}` is equivalent to `\omit`, `\multispan{2}` to `\omit\span\omit` and so on. The `\multicolumn` macro of LaTeX is built upon the same idea

```
% latex.ltx, line 5053:
\long\def\multicolumn#1#2#3{\multispan{#1}\begingroup
  \@mkpream{#2}%
  \def\@sharp{#3}\set@typeset@protect
  \let\@startpbox\@@startpbox\let\@endpbox\@@endpbox
  \@arstrut \@preamble\hbox{}\endgroup\ignorespaces}
```

It first does `\multispan{#1}` (defined exactly as in Plain) and then proceeds to build a “local” alignment preamble using the same `\@mkpream` used by `tabular` and `array` to evaluate their mandatory argument.

Why did Knuth use the same primitive for two very different meanings? In order to save space; TeX was written when computer memory space was low, and saving on a definition was important. Since `\span` can only appear in `\halign` (or `\valign`, of course), it's not a problem.

A devious usage of `\span` in the first meaning appears in the solution of exercise 20.16 in the TeXbook

> The following shouldn't be taken too seriously, but it does work:
>
> ```
> {\setbox0=\vbox{\halign{#{\c\span\d}\cr
>        \let\next=0\edef\next#1{\gdef\next{\b#1}}\next\cr}}}
>  \let\a=\next
> ```

The exercise is about defining `\a` to be equivalent to `\b` (fully expanded) followed by `\c` (not expanded) and by `\d` (expanded just once) without using `\noexpand` and `\the`. For instance, if we have

```
\def\foo{xy\baz}
\def\baz{z}
\def\b{\foo\foo}
\def\c{--}
\def\d{\baz}
```

we want to define `\a` to have as its replacement text

```
xyzxyz\c\baz
```

The `\setbox0=\vbox{` part is just to use `\halign` without any output. Now TeX evaluates the `\halign` preamble as `#{\c\baz}\cr`, because `\span` causes a one level expansion of `\d`. The only cell contains

```
\let\next=0\edef\next#1{\gdef\next{\b#1}}\next
```

that, according to the rules, is used in place of `#` in the preamble, so that the input stream becomes

```
\let\next=0\edef\next#1{\gdef\next{\b#1}}\next{\c\baz}\cr
```

The `\cr` just ends the cell, so it's not relevant. Because of `\let\next=0`, `\next` becomes unexpandable, so `\edef` causes `\next` to be defined as if it had been

```
\def\next#1{\gdef\next{<full expansion of \b>#1}}
```

and so `\next{\c\baz}` will dutifully execute

```
\gdef\next{<full expansion of \b>\c\baz}
```

and the final `\let\a=\next` ends it all.

This explains well that `\span` does only *one* step of expansion.

---

A different solution with e-TeX (it doesn't use `\noexpand` and `\the`, after all), would be

```
\edef\a{\b\unexpanded\expandafter{\expandafter\c\d}}
```

Comment: What is exactly happening in the solution of exercise 20.16? It would be nice to have an explanation.

Comment: @Manuel I was writing it.

Comment: Great answer. Just one thing: I think you are missing a closed brace in `\def\next#1{\gdef\next{<full expansion of \b>#1}`, which should be `\def\next#1{\gdef\next{<full expansion of \b>#1}}`. First closed brace for `\next`'s argument, second one ends definition.

Comment: Having no idea what `\halign` was, I googled and found [this](http://www.volkerschatz.com/tex/halign.html). Linking it here in case others may need it. And you're welcome. Thank _you_ in fact.

Comment: And [here is `\valign`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/how-to-use-valign).

Comment: if `\expandafter` is allowed, it is easy to come up with alternatives, but perhaps it was also forbidden ? (and anyway `shouldn't be taken too seriously` is as incipit).