# Why does center not center \halign?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\halign{\vrule \hfil # \hfil & \hfil # \hfil \vrule \cr
a & b \cr\noalign{\hrule}
c & d \cr\noalign{\hrule}
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I'd expect to get the simple table produced with `\halign` centered in the page. However, it is not, as the picture below shows.

[image]

`\centering` also has no effect. Why does that happen?

Comment: This is consistent with most other primitives that make boxes `center` would have no effect on `\hbox{a}` either. Compare with LaTeX commands such as `\mbox{a}` (or `tabular`) which are centred.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One might be tempted of using low level commands also in LaTeX; however there are some subtleties in them that are not easy to grasp at the beginning.

One of these subtleties is that `\halign` is a *vertical command*, so when found it causes vertical mode to start; if TeX is in horizontal mode when it scans `\halign`, it quits it by issuing `\par`.

This is proved by the following test file (Plain TeX):

```
a\def\par{PAR\endgraf\let\par\endgraf}bc\halign{#\cr HALIGN\cr}def
\bye
```

that outputs

[image]

The temporary redefinition of `\par` is aimed at showing that `\par` is effectively executed.

When TeX is in vertical mode, it simply stacks boxes without making paragraphs; therefore `\centering` (which is in effect in `center`) does nothing, because it only influences paragraphs. Thus your `\halign` will be printed flush with the left margin, since `\tabskip` is normally zero. The `\tabskip` glue in force at the moment `\halign` is scanned is added the left of every box formed by `\halign` (one box for every alignment row) and between any two alignment cells unless another `\tabskip` is specified. Read chapter 22 in the TeXbook for more information, but it's not easy.

How can one make `\halign` part of a paragraph? By hiding it inside something that can and that can also contain it: a `\vbox` is usually employed (the most common device for centering tables in Plain TeX is to use `$$\vbox{\halign{...}}$$`; don't try it in LaTeX). While `\vbox` doesn't by itself start a paragraph, it doesn't interrupt it either, so

```
\begin{center}
\leavevmode\vbox{\halign{...}}
\end{center}
```

will center your alignment.

Use `tabular`; you'll be on the safe side.

Comment: you mention `$$\halign{...}$$` in Plain, but doesn't one still need a `\vcenter` or `\vbox` around `\halign`?

Comment: @jfbu Of course!

Comment: And I certainly will @egreg. The reason I used it is I had a huge array which I wanted to convert to tabular for text mode, and since it was a table of LaTeX commands the column defaults (column 1 math mode for the commands, column 3 in `\texttt` with a leading backslash for the code) were decidedly handy. I've only just come across it thanks to [`\span`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203426/what-is-the-command-span).

Comment: @MickG you can specify columns as math mode and texttt using tabular (array package version) no need for \halign for that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'll look into that sooner or later, though I'd never heard of that package.

Comment: @MickG `array` is part of the core latex release.

Comment: @davidcarlisle that doesn't imply I must have heard of it, does it :)? I bet there are lots of packages I have but have nevere heard of :). Anyway I'll look into this and learn about `array`. When I have time. Or when I need to.

Comment: @MickG no, but it means you've _got_ it:-)

Comment: @davidcarlisle Ok let's say your comment had two possible interpretations: 1) it's in the core, so you should know about it 2) it's in he core so you have it (and its documentation as well), and you don't need to download it. You probably meant the second, but for some reason I selected the first. That's all. And again, I'll look into this and see how it works when the time comes. Thanks for the info :).

Answer (score 6):

The `\halign` builds horizontal boxes which are put on the surrounding vertical list, there are insensitive to the `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` obeyed by the paragraph builder.

You can try to center using this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\halign{\vrule \hfil # \hfil & \hfil # \hfil \vrule \cr
a & b \cr\noalign{\hrule}
c & d \cr\noalign{\hrule}
}


\tabskip 0pt plus 1000pt minus 1000pt 
\halign to \hsize{\tabskip0pt\vrule \hfil # \hfil & \hfil # \hfil \vrule 
\tabskip 0pt plus 1000pt minus 1000pt \cr
a & b \cr\noalign{\hrule}
c & d \cr\noalign{\hrule}
}

\end{document}
```

However, the `\hrule` extends the whole `\hsize` width.

> [image: halign]

We can put the `\halign` in a `\vbox`.

```
\bigskip

\centering
\noindent\vbox{\halign{\vrule \hfil # \hfil & \hfil # \hfil \vrule \cr
a & b \cr\noalign{\hrule}
c & d \cr\noalign{\hrule}
}}
```

> [image: halign in a box]

Comment: OK that works. It _is_ curious though that only `\centering` or only `\vbox` are not enough. Why is that?

Comment: Basically, `\centering` is `\rightskip \@flushglue \leftskip \@flushglue` plus some more stuff. But these skips are obeyed by the paragraph builder when it breaks a paragraph into lines. The `\halign` is another way to create horizontal lines, it has no reason to obey `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`. With a `\vbox` we then trigger the paragraph builder.

Comment: I just tried it on more complex tables, and it doesn't seem to work. But I'm afraid posting the actual problem means posting too much code :).

Comment: In my previous comment: "with a `\noindent\vbox` we trigger the paragraph builder" was meant (a `\vbox` by itself does not switch to horizontal mode; in `LaTeX` on the other hand all box commands such as  `\usebox`, `\parbox`, ... force to leave vertical mode). You don't say what did not work with more complex tables. The advantage of `\halign` is to be able to spread over multiple pages. As soon as you put it in a box (like `tabular` does) you can't if not later "undoing" the box to extract from it its lines.