# Why is \halign not centered in display math mode?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, alignment

This is centered:

```
$$\vbox{\halign{#\cr A\cr}}$$
```

Why this is not centered?

```
$$\halign{#\cr A\cr}$$
```

*BTW, why `\hbox{\halign{#\cr A\cr}}` does not work?*

Comment: refer to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203491/why-does-center-not-center-halign

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\halign` is a *vertical* command, meaning that it starts vertical mode when encountered, as this example shows

```
\parindent=0pt % To see the left margin
Foo bar baz \halign{#\cr A\cr} bar foo baz
\bye
```

[image]

Vertical commands raise an error when used in restricted horizontal mode (i.e. within `\hbox`).

However, there exists the *display alignment*, specified as

```
$$⟨assignments⟩ \halign⟨box specification⟩{...} ⟨assignments⟩$$
```

where the ⟨*assignments*⟩ are optional things like parameter changes that do not produce any math lists.
Such an alignment is shifted by `\displayindent` and surrounded
by `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` glue. (From TeX by Topic, Sec 25.2.1.) Usually within a paragraph `\displayindent` is `0pt` (but `\parshape` or `\hangindent` can change this); that's why you see a left-aligned formula

```
\parindent=0pt % To see the left margin
Foo bar baz
$$\halign{#\cr A\cr}$$
Foo bar baz
$$\displayindent=1em\halign{#\cr A\cr}$$
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Answer to exercise 22.14 in TeXbook uses `$$\vbox{\halign...`. But answers to 22.9, 22.7 and 22.6 consistently use `$$\halign...`. Just wondering...

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Can't look at it right now. Hopefully later...

Comment: @IgorLiferenko the first one is a normal alignment in a vbox, that is then centred by `$$`, the second form is the special display alignment construct as described in this answer.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko 22.9 has `\halign to\displaywidth`, the other two have `\halign to\hsize`.